# ORACLE question about identifiers

Tags: sql, oracle

If you create a function and name it is there any way to use that name later in your statement?

For example in the code below I named the sellprice-buyprice as `PROFIT` but I can't seem to use that again as it errors as an invalid identifier.  If I can't do that, please let me know how I would display the max profit entry in that column.

```
SELECT item, buyprice, sellprice,
sellprice-buyprice as “PROFIT”
FROM auctions
WHERE PROFIT = (select MAX(PROFIT) from auctions);
```

Comment: Does the minus caracter is authorized in identifier ?

Comment: @Luc M: It's actually the minus operator, `sellprice` minus `buyprice`. I agree that it looks somewhat ambiguous. I myself prefer spaces around operators.

Comment: @Andriy I quit programming Cobol last year. The minus sign may be in variable name. I still keep some old habits :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this statement:
`select * from (select item, buyprice, sellprice, sellprice-buyprice as “PROFIT”
from auctions order by 4 desc) where rownum = 1;`

Comment: That returned one item but not the one with the highest profit.

Comment: Thanks much!  If you have a second, can you explain to me how the end of that works?  (order by and rownum part)

Comment: Sure. In my first example there was a mistake - when oracle gets "where rownum > x" clause, it fetches only x rows and then sorts them by order clause. In second try oracle selects all rows, then orders them by 'sellprice-buyprice' value (descending). At this point first row in a query is a row with a highest profit value. Then, 'select * from (...) where rownum = 1' just selects first row. That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

You would use the function name in the where clause, referencing the alias is not valid there.

```
SELECT item, buyprice, sellprice,
sellprice-buyprice as “PROFIT”
FROM auctions
WHERE sellprice-buyprice = (select MAX(PROFIT) from auctions);
```

Or you can do the following if you really want to use the alias

```
select item, buyprice, sellprice, profit
from
(
  SELECT item, buyprice, sellprice, sellprice-buyprice as “PROFIT”
  FROM auctions)
)
WHERE PROFIT = (select MAX(PROFIT) from auctions);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using subqueries, as has already been suggested, you could achieve this through subquery refactoring:

```
WITH auctions_p AS (SELECT   item,
                             buyprice,
                             sellprice,
                             sellprice - buyprice AS profit
                      FROM   auctions)
SELECT   item,
         buyprice,
         sellprice,
         profit
  FROM   auctions_p
 WHERE   profit = (SELECT   MAX(profit) FROM auctions_p);
```

If you're going to use this a lot and you're using 11g, you could make this calculation permanently available by defining it as a virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE auctions ADD (profit AS (sellprice - buyprice));

SELECT   item,
         buyprice,
         sellprice,
         profit
  FROM   auctions
 WHERE   profit = (SELECT   MAX(profit) FROM auctions);
```